# Explode a dict - Get all combinations of the values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, cartesian-product

I want to get all combinations of the values in a dictionary as multiple dictionaries (each containing every key of the original but only one value of the original values). Say I want to parametrize a function call with:

```
kwargs = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
```

How do I get a list of all the combinations like this:

```
combinations = [{'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3},
                {'a': 2, 'b': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3},
                {'a': 3, 'b': 1}, {'a': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 3}]
```

There can be an arbitary amount of keys in the original `kwargs` and each value is garantueed to be an iterable but the number of values is not fixed.

If possible: the final `combinations` should be a generator (not a list).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can flatten the `kwargs` to something like this

```
>>> kwargs = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> flat = [[(k, v) for v in vs] for k, vs in kwargs.items()]
>>> flat
[[('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)], [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]]
```

Then, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) like this

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [dict(items) for items in product(*flat)]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 1},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 1},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 2},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 2},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 3},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 3},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 3}]
```

`itertools.product` actually returns an iterator. So you can get the values on demand and build your dictionaries. Or you can use `map`, which also returns an iterator.

```
>>> for item in map(dict, product(*flat)):
...     print(item)
...
...
{'b': 1, 'a': 1}
{'b': 1, 'a': 2}
{'b': 1, 'a': 3}
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
{'b': 2, 'a': 2}
{'b': 2, 'a': 3}
{'b': 3, 'a': 1}
{'b': 3, 'a': 2}
{'b': 3, 'a': 3}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just another way, building the value tuples first and then combining with keys afterwards (pretty much the opposite of @thefourtheye's way :-).

```
>>> combinations = (dict(zip(kwargs, vs)) for vs in product(*kwargs.values()))
>>> for c in combinations:
        print(c)

{'a': 1, 'b': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 3}
{'a': 2, 'b': 1}
{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
{'a': 2, 'b': 3}
{'a': 3, 'b': 1}
{'a': 3, 'b': 2}
{'a': 3, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be dependent on implementation details, as it requires the key and value iterators to have the same ordering? Dict has no ordering requirements and I don't think there's any guarantee that those iterators have to have the same order.

Comment: @zstewart Why not just check the documentation? It says they have the same order and even gives the example `pairs = zip(d.values(), d.keys())`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Do you mean the ["Dictionary view objects" documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)