# Find all possible combinations of two lists

Tags: python, cartesian-product

Given two lists of arbitrary length:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3']
```

`list1` is the list of objects and `list2` is the possible values of each object.How do I find all possible combinations of these two lists (I'm not sure if that's the right terminology)

Expected output:

```
[
    [('a', '1'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '1')],
    [('a', '1'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '2')],
    [('a', '1'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '3')],
    [('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '1')],
    [('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '2')],
    [('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '3')],
    [('a', '3'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '1')],
    [('a', '3'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '2')],
    [('a', '3'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '3')],
    # etc
]
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254205/explode-a-dict-get-all-combinations-of-the-values-in-a-dictionary, which is basically the same thing with a different input format (`{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3]}` in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get Cartesian product of input iterables, and zip them :

```
from itertools import product

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['1', '2', '3']
print([list(zip(a, p)) for p in product(b,repeat=3)])
```

Output:

```
[[('a', '1'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '1')], [('a', '1'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '2')], [('a', '1'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '3')], [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '1')], [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '2')], [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')], [('a', '1'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '1')], [('a', '1'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '2')], [('a', '1'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '3')], [('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '1')], [('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '2')], [('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '3')], [('a', '2'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '1')], [('a', '2'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '2')], [('a', '2'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')], [('a', '2'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '1')], [('a', '2'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '2')], [('a', '2'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '3')], [('a', '3'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '1')], [('a', '3'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '2')], [('a', '3'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '3')], [('a', '3'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '1')], [('a', '3'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '2')], [('a', '3'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')], [('a', '3'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '1')], [('a', '3'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '2')], [('a', '3'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '3')]]
```

Comment: Perfect! as an improvement, I made the last line `[list(zip(a, p)) for p in product(b,repeat=len(a)]` to allow for any length list