# Cartesian product of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, cartesian-product

I am trying to write some python code to get the following output, all permutations. Values of `region` and `gender` are probabilities, `result` reflects a product of given events combination.

It seems that can be achieved by using `itertools` and `apply`, but I'm not quite sure about the specific implementations.

Inputs:

```
region = {'east': 0.5, 'north': 0.20, 'south': 0.10, 'west': 0.20}
gender = {'female': 0.70, 'male': 0.30}
```

Desired output:

```
result = {('east','female'):0.35, 
('east','male'):0.15,
('north','female'):0.14,
('north','male'):0.06,
('south','female'):0.07,
('south','male'):0.03,
('west','female'):0.14,
('west','male'):0.06}
```

Comment: Tangentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254205/explode-a-dict-get-all-combinations-of-the-values-in-a-dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Two dictionaries

Simply use *dictionary comprehension* with nested loops:

```
{(k1,k2):v1*v2 for k1,v1 in region.items() for k2,v2 in gender.items()}
```

So here we construct, for every `k1,v1` in `region` and for every `k2,v2` in `gender` an element in the dictionary with key `(k1,k2)` that maps to `v1*v2`.

This generates:

```
>>> {(k1,k2):v1*v2 for k1,v1 in region.items() for k2,v2 in gender.items()}
{('north', 'female'): 0.13999999999999999, ('west', 'female'): 0.13999999999999999, ('east', 'female'): 0.35, ('south', 'male'): 0.03, ('north', 'male'): 0.06, ('east', 'male'): 0.15, ('south', 'female'): 0.06999999999999999, ('west', 'male'): 0.06}
```

The fact that you see `0.13999...` instead of `0.14` is due to rounding errors with floating points, and has nothing to do with the dictionary comprehension itself.

## Arbitrary number of dictionaries

It can also happen that you want to calculate the Cartesian product of an arbitrary number of dictionaries (note however this will scale exponentially, so the number of dictionaries is definitely limited due to memory limitations). In that case you could use the following procedure:

```
from operator import mul, getitem
from functools import reduce
from itertools import product, starmap

def cartesian_dictionary(*args,fold=mul):
    return { ks : reduce(fold,starmap(getitem,zip(args,ks)))
                  for ks in product(*args) }
```

resulting in:

```
>>> cartesian_dictionary({'east': 0.5, 'north': 0.20, 'south': 0.10, 'west': 0.20},{'female': 0.70, 'male': 0.30})
{('east', 'female'): 0.35, ('west', 'female'): 0.13999999999999999, ('south', 'male'): 0.03, ('north', 'male'): 0.06, ('south', 'female'): 0.06999999999999999, ('north', 'female'): 0.13999999999999999, ('west', 'male'): 0.06, ('east', 'male'): 0.15}
```

But it gives additional flexibility:

- three or more dictionaries, like:

  ```
  >>> cartesian_dictionary({'a':2,'b':3},{'c':0.5,'d':1},{'e':1,'f':2})
  {('b', 'c', 'e'): 1.5, ('a', 'c', 'f'): 2.0, ('b', 'd', 'f'): 6, ('a', 'c', 'e'): 1.0, ('b', 'd', 'e'): 3, ('a', 'd', 'f'): 4, ('b', 'c', 'f'): 3.0, ('a', 'd', 'e'): 2}
  ```
- other way to "fold" values:

  ```
  >>> cartesian_dictionary({'a':2,'b':3},{'c':0.5,'d':1},fold=operator.add)
  {('a', 'd'): 3, ('b', 'd'): 4, ('b', 'c'): 3.5, ('a', 'c'): 2.5}
  ```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use itertools, you could do this:

```
from itertools import product

d = {(reg[0], gen[0]): reg[1]*gen[1]
     for (reg, gen) in product(region.items(), gender.items())}
```

although i strongly prefer [Willem Van Onsem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44018808/4954037).

the itertools version could be beneficial if you did not store the all the results in a dictionary, but would just iterate over them, do something with the result and discard them. something like:

```
for (reg, gen) in product(region.items(), gender.items()):
    key = (reg[0], gen[0])
    value = reg[1]*gen[1]
    # do something with key, value
```